# Virus using input from victims mic to generate encryption keys

Tags: encryption, virus, random, key-generation, audio

I am a software engineer from Bucharest and I've created an audio based encryption and authentication application called WaveCrypt. It basically allows users to encrypt (AES) their files with an WaveKey - a unique audio fingerprint that can be obtained from an Wave file (thus the name of the application. I've chosen this specific format because it is not compressed) . You can get that wave file from an offline source (CD or you simply record it live with the built in application plugin) or an online source (YouTube).

Think of it as an password based encryption that uses an audio input instead.

While I was reading some good operating systems architecture materials, a new idea sparked into my mind. While you can use it for good purposes, it has a tremendous potential to be used for bad causes too. Think about it. You can design an encryption virus that generates its encryption key directly from the victim's microphone. By using this random audio input as key you can make sure that the keys you will use are completely impossible to reproduce. A true, natural one way function.

I do not intend to create such a virus (as you can imagine, I wouldn't post it here, right?) but it is just a playful thought that I wanted to share with you.

What do you think about audio based encryption malware?

Comment: Current ransomware uses server-generated keys or keys obtained from OS CSRNGs. I doubt that these keys are any easier to "reproduce" than random audio noise (ignoring the offchance of a vulnerability in the OS CSRNG.)

Comment: I don't see what problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you properly interpret the intentions of encrypting malware creators and operators. If they cannot decrypt, their business is not sustainable.

Comment: Note: you should reword this as otherwise it WILL get closed. Asking for opinions like in "What do you think [...]?" Is explicite not allowed to ask here.

Comment: *"(as you can imagine, I wouldn't post it here, right?)"*: One of the elements which lead to the identification and arrestation of [Silk Road's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk_Road_(marketplace)) founder was [a question he asked on StackOverflow](https://youtu.be/7G1LjQSYM5Q?t=1400). Imagination should never be limited by preconceptions ;) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use some "natural" sound, you have lots of redudancy in it and this reduces the key strength (this may or may not be critical to your application).

Because you cannot reproduce your sound key, you'll have to store it (in a passphase-locked key store). With this condition, a randomly generated strong key is always better.

Comment: i find that the middle-right 10 bits of each 16 bit wav sample scores well on `ent`, even without whitening. make sure to turn off noise and echo reduction for maximum entropy. Music is actually better than noise/static.

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting idea.

I suppose that malware could indeed obtain a very hard to reproduce key like this, however there could be some issues :

- the target's microphone is muted
- there is a very low amount of sound in the room - no sound is captured

I would suggest to have a fallback mechanism to a more classic key creation system if such conditions were detected.

I suppose that this technique is not used for this reason. But very interesting nonetheless, never thought about it :)

Of course the WaveCrypt application looks just great for non-malicious usage, since in that case the user would make sure that sound is properly captured

Comment: If there is a very low amount of sound in the room and the microphone's not muted, the microphone should at least record some white noise. (A random noise, so could be interesting for a RNG)

Comment: I believe that some modern microphones (used by gamers notably) have a minimum sound level treschold under which they don't send the signals.- at least those don't appear in the "detected sounds" visual bars on a Windows machine, whereas a classic mic shows a very small wiggling bar - this is not a very objective affirmation, I admit it is worth verifying more thoroughly

Comment: Well if it doesn't send anything you must be correct. I'm a bit outdated with my old microphone which doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I agree it could be done, but that does not mean that the results would be any good or that it would have any advantages what so ever over existing methods to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

What you have invented is essentially a random number generator, and not "a true one way function". A one way function is something that alwasy generates the same output for the same input, but can not be reversed. You use one way functions to hash things - how would you hash something with this scheme?

So if it's a random number generator, is it cryptographically secure? While there is some white noise everywhere, there is also a lot of patterns in sound. How good the result is depends on how you sample and filter the audio, but it is possible that this could be done in a good way. But why bother when there are already good CSPRNG's available without playing around with the mic?

You suggest this should be used for generating encryption keys. This should indeed be done with a CSPRNG. But so far you have not shown why your generator would be better than the ordinary ones that are available on any system.

In summary, you have invented a complicated way to do something that can already be easily done.